# Posting Ajax data with an additional variable

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am having trouble with a jquery script to send a serialized form data along with a modified variable.i have tried a couple different methods, but the added variable is not posting.

I have tried a few methods, the best I think using jquery.param(), however, it is not passing the variable message through.

```
// Code the input (message)
            var message = $('textarea[name="content"]').html($('#emailbody').code());


                // Submit the form using AJAX.
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'mailer.php',
                    data: $(form).serialize()+$.param(message),
                })
```

I am guessing my syntax for passing the variable is incorrect. Any tips?

Thank you,
Nigel

Comment: What is the `.code()` in `$('#emailbody').code()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the textarea with name `content` is within the form then just set its value and serialize the form

```
$('textarea[name="content"]').val($('#emailbody').code());
// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mailer.php',
    data: $(form).serialize(),
})
```

Else you could try

```
// Submit the form using AJAX.
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'mailer.php',
    data: $(form).serialize() + '&content=' + encodeURIComponent($('#emailbody').code()),
})
```

Comment: thanks. The textarea is in the same form, however, it is coded, so I have had to modify it before re-adding it to the form (it is a summernote.js input)

Comment: @npasco in that case there is no need to use any of that.. see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/457dr535/3/

Comment: hmmm... I tried this, however, the resultant POST variable shows the html code.

Comment: @npasco then what do you want... the editor will give you the html code

Comment: doh!... my bad, I apologise. There was no issue with the above, but, there was an extra space between one of the php mail headers (i.e. $email_header . = "something";) that was stopping the html from displaying proper.
Your answer above is fantastic, and hopefully usefull to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
data : $(form).serialize() +  '&' + $.param(message)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
data :{'form': $('#form').serialize(),'content':$('#emailbody').code()}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a simple solution of your problem like below:

1. Have one hidden field inside  element.
   2.Before you post your form, assign variable value to hidden field like below:

   $('#HiddenFieldIdHere').val(variablevalue);
2. Then make ajax call like you did without appending variable value.

Comment: Good idea, it seems to do the job... however, the resultant POST is '[object Object]'... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
var message = $('#form_id').serialize();
```

$.ajax({
            url: "mailer.php",
            type: 'POST',
            data: message,
            success: function (data) {
              $("#form_result").html(data);
            }
    });